# row() function in arrayformula problem (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, row, array-formulas

Hi I'm trying to write the formula to automatically create bathes of converted data from first few columns but I've stumbled upon inconsistency.

In this formula the "naked" `ROW(A:A)` produces correct row but in offset function it always counts as first row.

Is there any way to circumvent this?

The function takes 6 inputs from C to H column, adds them in between `J$1:J$14` and `J$21:J$26` displays them vertically and it generates as many of that joined rows then transposed into one column as there are rows with data in A column as in "Working example"

```
=TRANSPOSE(split(join("|",ARRAYFORMULA(If(($A:$A)="","",join("|",J$1:J$14)&"|ROW="&ROW(A:A)&"|"&Join("|",offset(C1:H1,row(A:A)-1,0))&"|"&join("|",J$21:J$26)))),"|"))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FIz6QCjz0KHNuenD2ered-5NwhOr2IfAM7eQYF2rM3k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean by merges? Do you want the cells to merge and then paste several values in the same merged cell? If column A has more than 1 row, do you want to put the values C1:H1 into J1:J14 and C2:H2 into J21:J26? Please explain more in detail.

Comment: it's suppossed to be making a J1:J14+C1:H1+J21:26 then J1:J14+C2:H2+J21:26 then J1:J14+C3:H3+J21:26 and then transposing them

Comment: I've added a working example to show what i'm trying to do

Comment: I still do not entirely understand what the function is supposed to do, but `ROW(A:A)` does not sound right. `A:A` is a column, if you want to retrieve all rows in the A column, then probably you need `ROWS(A:A)`